# Failed to install ROS indigo on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, ubuntu-14.04, ros, raspberry-pi2

I tried the following instructions to install ROS indigo on my RPi2.
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

But in the step 2.2.2

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y -r --os=debian:wheezy
```

I got:

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rosdep] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rospkg] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-catkin-pkg] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rosdep]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rospkg]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-catkin-pkg]
```

Is there anybody can help me??

I tried following command to manually install python-rosdep

```
$ sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rosdep
```

It said:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-rosdep : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python-rospkg (>= 1.0.34) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

I have installed python-2.7.3. I don't know why it said "python >=2.7.1-0ubuntu2" is ont installable...

Kevin Kuei

Answer (score 1):

Oh... I found the statement in the installation guide:

Note: Rosdep may report that python-rosdep, python-catkin-pkg, python-rospkg, and python-rosdistro failed to install; however, you can ignore this error because they have already been installed with pip.

So.. those error message can be ignored.. :D